# Ensuring that all callbacks were completed before sending a new request through a DuplexChannel using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, winforms, duplex

I am experiencing some issues when using a Callback in a WCF project.

First, the server invokes some function `Foo` on the client which then forwards the request to a Windows Forms GUI:

**GUI CLASS**

```
delegate void DoForward();
public void ForwardToGui() {
    if (this.cmdSomeButton.InvokeRequired) {
        DoForward d = new DoForward(ForwardToGui);
            this.Invoke(d);
        }
        else {
            Process(); // sets result variable in callback class as soon as done
        }
    }
}
```

**CALLBACK CLASS**

```
object _m = new object();
private int _result;
public int result {
    get { return _result; }
    set {
        _result = value; 
        lock(_m) {
            Monitor.PulseAll(_m);
        }
    }
}

[OperationContract]
public int Foo() {
    result = 0;
    Program.Gui.ForwardToGui();
    lock(_m) {
        Monitor.Wait(_m, 30000);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem now is that the user should be able to cancel the process, which doesn't work properly:

**SERVER INTERFACE**

```
[OperationContract]
void Cleanup();
```

**GUI CLASS**

```
private void Gui_FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Program.callbackclass.nextAction = -1; 
    // so that the monitor pulses and Foo() returns
    Program.server.Cleanup();
}
```

The problem with this is that `Cleanup()` hangs. However, when I close the form when `Process()` is not running, it works properly.

The source seems to be that the `Cleanup()` is called before the monitor pulses etc and therefore a new request is sent to the server before the last request from the server has not yet been responded.

How can I solve this problem? How can I ensure before calling `Cleanup()` that no `Foo()` is currently being executed?

Comment: I got too confused trying to piece the snippets of code together. Are the two code snippets headed "GUI Class" in the same GUI class? 

The first warning I'm seeing is that you're calling System.Windows.Form.Invoke instead of System.Windows.Forms.BeginInvoke. Is that intentional?

Comment: Both parts labeled with GUI class are the same class. I'm trying now. It seems that BeginInvoke did the job! Thanks :-) Would you mind posting your comment again as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first warning I'm seeing is that you're calling [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) instead of 
[BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx)

*Invoke* waits until the action has been completed on the other thread before returning, which can result in a deadlock in some situations.